# Monotone convergence theorem for a decreasing recursive sequence from $n>n_0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, recurrence-relations, monotone-class-theorem

Let a recursive sequence:
$$a(0)=a\in\mathbb{R};\\
a(n+1)=f(a(n));\\$$
if the sequence is decreasing but **not for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$**, e.g $a(n+1)\leq a(n) \,\, \forall \, n\geq 2$, it holds the monotone convergence theorem? So I can say that exists the limit of the sequence (even if the decrease holds from $n=2$)?

Comment: Surely. Convergence of $(a_{n_0+1},a_{n_0+2},...)$ is equivalent to convergence of $(a_1,a_2,...)$.

Comment: Yes. The fact that a sequence converges or diverges *does not* depend on its first terms.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe The fact that a sequence converges or diverges does not depend on its first terms follows from the definition of the limit of a sequence, right?

Comment: @gui Yes indeed. The definition of the convergence is $\forall \varepsilon  > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, .....$ : if you change the first terms of your sequence (or if you add or remove terms at the beginning), you will eventually get another $N \in \mathbb{N}$, but the definition will still hold.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is required that the sequence is $\textit eventually$ monotonic, since it would still mean that $\textit eventually$ all the terms in the sequence are less than $\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$. However, it is also required by the monotonic convergence theorem that the sequence is bounded. It doesn't look like you have given how $f$ is defined.

Comment: As a corollary it is said that if it is not bounded the limit exists the same but is not finite.

Comment: I guess if you want to say $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are limits then sure that makes sense (In this case, an example with no limit at all would be the sequence $(1,-1,2,-2....)$. Again you still haven't shown how $f$ is defined though, so I cannot say much more.